# How to properly concatenate str_values from dataframe rows with NaN values in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Smash rows from dataframe with NaN values

I have this dataframe:

| descritpion | quantity | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| This is the description | 2 | 100,00 |
| for the first row |  |  |
| Row number 2 | 10 | 150,00 |
| Row number 3 | 15 | 200,00 |

As we can see, the description for the first row takes 2 lines, but I have no way to know that description is that long.
I have tried to iterate over rows, and if those rows have `NaN.sum() == len(df.shape[1]) -1` then I take the `temp_description_col = dataframe.description.iloc[row_index_iterator]` and join the descriptions to the last row with  `join(dataframe.description.iloc[row_index_iterator - 1].join(temp_description_col)`. I also have tried `out = (df.bfill().groupby(['Importe'], as_index=False).agg({'Concepto': ' '.join}))` but it creates the first row with the smashed rows.

The problem I found is, that ofcourse seems very rudimentary to check ever row and overwrite the description from the last row if I find nans in all columns except one and the possibility that the description with nans belongs to the rows after. For example:

| descritpion | quantity | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| This is the description |  |  |
| for the first row | 2 | 100,00 |
| Row 2 description |  |  |
| and Row2 continuation | 15 | 200,00 |

In this dataframe we can check that the first row descrption belongs to the second row, since the rest of the columns have NaN, and the third description belongs to the 4th row, which by smashing them, it is the second row.

Wanted output:

df1

| descritpion | quantity | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| This is the description for the first row | 2 | 100,00 |
| Row number 2 | 10 | 150,00 |
| Row number 3 | 15 | 200,00 |

df2

| descritpion | quantity | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| This is the description for the first row | 2 | 100,00 |
| Row 2 descriptionand Row2 continuation | 15 | 200,00 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the general logic, you can use a custom aggregation:

```
# group empty rows (except on "description") with previous ones
group = df.drop(columns='description').notna().any(axis=1).cumsum()

# concatenate "description" else get first value
agg = {c: 'first' for c in df}
agg['description'] = ' '.join

out = df.groupby(group).agg(agg)
```

Output:

```
                                 description  quantity   value
1  This is the description for the first row       2.0  100,00
2                               Row number 2      10.0  150,00
3                               Row number 3      15.0  200,00
```

Now to handle the case in which you can have an empty first row, use:

```
m = df.drop(columns='description').notna().any(axis=1)
group = m.shift(-1 if (m.iloc[0]==False) else 0, fill_value=False).cumsum()

agg = {c: 'first' for c in df}
agg['description'] = ' '.join

out = df.groupby(group).agg(agg)
```

Output:

```
                                 description  quantity   value
1  This is the description for the first row       2.0  100,00
2    Row 2 description and Row2 continuation      15.0  200,00
```

Comment: Impressive. Thank you very much. This is just what I was looking for, using the api in a comprehensive way and clean code. I was trying to send you a pm but seems like stackoverflow has no pms... So, how can I reach this level of understanding the api? Any course I can do or daily practices? Because I think i would have never know how to do that, even when i've been searching pandas documentatio for a couple of days...

Comment: @Jose sorry, there is no secret recipe or magic courses ;) You have to read, try, fail, practice, and in the end you'll progress.

Comment: Sorry for being a dissaster and having more problems with the same situation. Right now, I'm implementing it and since I'm extracting tables from invoices with tabula, it creates some wierd tables. In this case:

| Cuantity | Uds | Description | Price | Total |
| ----- | ----- | ----- | ----- | ----- |
|    |      | Row 1 description | 10 | 10 |
| 1 | Uds |   |    |   |
|    |      |  row1 continuation |    |    |

This is giving me  the TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found and I don't really know how to debug it.

Comment: This likely to means that you have NaNs in the "description" column. Try to `dropna(how='all')` as an initial step.